# Why does adding two if statements to my const throw an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I currently have my const set up like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { ButtonToolbar, Alert } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { CommentsModal } from '../comments-modal';


export const CommentsListBeijing = ({ comments }) => (
  comments.length > 0 ? <ButtonToolbar className="comment-list">
    {comments.map((com) => (
      <CommentsModal key={ com._id } comment={ com } city={com.city} person={com.person} location={com.location} title={com.title} content={com.content} fileLink={com.fileLink} timestamp={com.timestamp} createdBy={com.createdBy}/>
    ))}
  </ButtonToolbar> :
  <Alert bsStyle="warning">No sparks yet. Please add some!</Alert>
);

CommentsListBeijing.propTypes = {
  comments: React.PropTypes.array,
};
```

If I then want to add an other if statement my code throws an error. I don't understand why.

This is my new code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { ButtonToolbar, Alert } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { CommentsModal } from '../comments-modal';

export const CommentsListBeijing = ({ comments }) => (
  if (comments.length > 0 ) {
    <ButtonToolbar className="comment-list">
    {comments.map((com) => (
      return com.adminSpark ? 
        /* something admin-related */ : 
        <CommentsModal 
          key={ com._id } 
          comment={ com } 
          city={com.city} 
          person={com.person} 
          location={com.location} 
          title={com.title} 
          content={com.content} 
          fileLink={com.fileLink} 
          timestamp={com.timestamp} 
          createdBy={com.createdBy} />
    ))}
    </ButtonToolbar> :
    <Alert bsStyle="warning">No sparks yet. Please add some!</Alert>
 );
CommentsListBeijing.propTypes = {
  comments: React.PropTypes.array,
};
```

When I try to run my code now I get this error: "imports/ui/components/beijing/comments-list-beijing.js:6:2: Unexpected token (6:2)"

Line 6 refers to "if (comments.length > 0 ) {"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thats not another `if` statement, your syntax is just wrong. Your closing `</ButtonToolbar>` should probably be in `if` and the `<Alert...>` should be in an `else`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't using any `if` statements in the first example. You're using the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

The problem is that in your first example, you only had an *expression* so the arrow function will implicitly return it's value.

When using an `if`, you now have a *statement*.

Example:

```js
// Compiles just fine
var f = () => (
  (true) ? 1 : 0
);
// Could also write it as
// var f = () => true ? 1 : 0;
console.log(f());
```

```js
// Will not compile
var f = () => (
  if (true) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
);
console.log(f());
```

All you need to do is wrap your arrow function body in curly braces.

```js
// Now it works
var f = () => { // <--
  if (true) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}; // <--
console.log(f());
```

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me understand. I didn't know there was a difference between a normal if/else statement and a ternary operator.

Thank you for taking the time to write a reply.

Comment: @Deelux No worries. I'm glad I could help!